# texture atlas and batchNode : add the batchNode on stage?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

can you explain me why the `batchNode` loads the `texture atlas` image, and we then create a `ccsprite`, that we push back to the `batchNode`, and we finally add the `batchNode` to the `stage` (instead of the sprite)? Does it work like the `uinavigation` stack, the "image" on top is the image showed onscreen?

```
spriteBatchNode = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"..."];
my_sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"...png"];
[spriteBatchNode addChild:my_sprite];
[self addChild:spriteBatchNode];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CCSpriteBatchNode and CCSprite are both derived from CCNode.

Instead of adding the CCSprite nodes to your game scene or layer node directly, you add them to the spriteBatchNode. And the spriteBatchNode you'll add to the scene or layer node.

Think of this like a tree structure:

```
scene
   layer1
      sprite1
      sprite2
   layer2
      spritebatchnode
         sprite1
         sprite2
         sprite3
         sprite4
```